# Get Data from 2 tables in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have one table which has all the api audit information - Table name : **api_audit**

I have one table which has extra information about every api call - Table name : **api_audit_info**

Inside **api_audit** I have primary key as "**transaction_id**".

I want all the data from **api_audit** table and some data from **api_audit_info** table.

I have written a custom query like -
`@Query(select c from ApiAudit c INNER JOIN ApiAudiInfo t ON c.transactionId = t.msgId)`

But the issue is that the result type that I am getting this way contains only ApiAudit type data.
What shall I do to get data from both the tables. Please help.

Note: I am using JpaRepository as I need paginated data.

I am fairly new to Spring boot and JPA so not sure exactly which direction to look to.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to join data from more than 1 table, I am using Jdbi.

[Here you have the official documentation:](https://jdbi.org/)

Remember to include the required dependencies and configure a bean for Jdbi in your project.

Then I create a repository class, POJO and query with all of the information which I need. For example:

```
select c.transaction_id as transactionId, t.name as name from ApiAudit c INNER JOIN ApiAudiInfo t ON c.transactionId = t.msgId
```

[Here you have some code samples from official documentation](https://in3code.dev/_posts/2020-05-11-intro-to-jdbi-and-spring/)

After you map your data to POJO, you can use

```
public PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total)
```

to return paginated data.

There is a big chance that there is a better solution, but this works for me every time.